# Compensate delay of non-symmetric (non-linear phase) filter

Tags: matlab, filters, delay, matched-filter, group-delay

Lets assume I want to apply a matched filter `h` which is non-symmetric to my signal `x` and the output is `y` in matlab:

```
y=filter(h,1,x);
```

Now I am interested in comparing the information between my filtered signal `y`and my input `x`. For this I want to compensate for the delay of the filter `h`.

When googling this topic I found the following [tutorial](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/compensate-for-the-delay-introduced-by-an-fir-filter.html) which handles linear-phase fir filters. Obviously in such a case the group delay is $\frac{N-1}{2}$ given that the filter has the length $N$.

```
%this is the example from matlab
delay = mean(grpdelay(h,1,128)); 
x = x(1:end-delay);
y(1:delay) = [];
```

However, I am aware that the group delay of a non symmetric filter is frequency depending and I am not sure how to proceed to align my signals in time to compare them. As I am interested in real time application the function `filtfilter` is not applicable.

So my question is, how do I estimate in the best way the time delay to align (sync?) my signals in time given the coefficients of a non-symmetric filter `h`?

```
delay = .... h ....? 
x = x(1:end-delay);
y(1:delay) = [];
```

The desired output should look like the red curve in the following figure

[image: AlignedSignals]

Here the signal in blue is the input signal `x` and in green the filtered signal `y`. However, I would like to to compensate for the delay of the green signal so that the input and output align in time as in the case of the red curve.

Comment: I think the solution lies in your definition of "time delay" of a filter with a delay that depends on frequency. There is no single way to align the input and output signals of such a filter. The question is what you really mean by "align".

Comment: I edited my question and added a plot.

Comment: It looks like cross-correlation should work here.

Comment: I see, but this would be an approach which works well for offline analysis, however, is there a way, knowing the shape of the non-symmetric filter, to estimate the delay in advance and apply it online? Or is your idea to apply cross-correlation in advance and estimate this delay for later online processing? Would this delay not be dependent on the shape of the input signal? In other words can I generalize the delay from a cross-correlation of one input signal to all kind of input signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filters have a low pass characteristic (which at least the one in your example appears to have), then a possibly useful measure for the delay is the center of gravity of the impulse response:

$$\hat{\tau}=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_nnh[n]}{\displaystyle\sum_nh[n]}\tag{1}$$

For more general impulse responses, other than low pass, you can modify $(1)$ by either taking magnitudes or squares of $h[n]$. Note that $(1)$ is the filter's group delay evaluated at DC.

Comment: First of all thank you, first tests indicate that this is a good estimation. Have you any source for this approach where the idea is elaborated?

Comment: @Irreducible: Great that it seems to work! Well, the center of gravity (center of mass) is of course a very general concept, which can be applied to any function. So I don't have a specific reference right now, but just for your intuition, imagine that $h[n]$ were a probability mass function of some random variable, then $(1)$ would be the expected value.

Comment: Thanks for the additional interpretation.